# goBack.focus() not working in win 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows-10

I am using IE 11 and here I am opening the popup window. There is a point from where I can turn my focus to the parent window.

The code is like this-

```
var goBack = window.open('', 'parent');
                goBack.focus();
```

Now, this works fine in all the IE 11 which I tested but fails in Win 10 pro version IE. And I not understanding why. Could anyone point me in right direction?

This is IE version which is **not working**

[image: IE version]

Update:I have tried something `window.opener.focus();` it works but same fails in chrome

Comment: Are you sure that `window.open` returns object that you're expect?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applicable for IE11 but from the https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx

**Internet Explorer 7 on Windows Vista**: Opening a new window from an application (other than the Internet Explorer process) may result in a null return value. This restriction occurs because Internet Explorer runs in protected mode, by default. One facet of protected mode prevents applications from having privileged access to Internet Explorer when that access spans process boundaries. Opening a new window by using this method generates a new process. For more information about protected mode, see [Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb250462(v=vs.85).aspx). This commonly occurs for applications that host the WebBrowser control.